# node.js conflicts: /sbin/node vs /usr/bin/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, linux

Bom dia pessoal !
Gostaria que alguém me exclarescesse muito bem esse conflito que surge na instalacao do nodejs ?

Agradeço!

Comment: experiemente http://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node

Comment: você quer instalar como /sbin/node ou /usr/bin/node ?

Comment: @FábioArsénio existe um conflito entre esses dois ai, preciso simplesmente saber de que se trata realmente. Qual a razao desse conflito e como resolver ? Estou a realisar um trabalho e preciso relatar esse erro. AGRADECO !

Comment: @Miguel seria melhor uma referencia em francês, tenho debilidades grave en inglês ... !! Mas contudo agradeço pelo seu apoio... GRATO !

Comment: Eles basicamente dizem a solução ser `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Comment: Tanto no debian como no ubuntu o nodejs força a utilização da package nodejs-legacy

Comment: @Miguel muito mais do que a soluçao o que mais importa-me é a copressao do "bug" ! Tipo o que se passou pra se instalar "nodejs-legacy" ? So pretendo compreeender esse conflito entre eses dois repertorios  ai ! GRATO PELA INTECAO .

Comment: Obrigado @FábioArsénio ! Mas porquê ? A que se deve isso ?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atencao  @FábioArsénio ! Olha acredito que nao estou a fazer sentir a minha pergunta, na verdade o problema ja tivera sido resolvido, gostaria no entanto saber a que se deve o conflito entre esses dois repertorios ? Porquê nodejs exige que o path para o binário seja usr/bin/node e não usr/bin/nodejs ? Estou a elaborar um relatorio e preciso explicar nao simplemente a resolucao do problema, mas também a causa !

Answer (score 0):

A **package** `node-js legacy` contém um **symlink** para o código do node-js, que exige que o **path** para o binário seja **usr/bin/node** e não **usr/bin/nodejs** como é no **Debian**. A **não** instalação do pacote legacy do nodejs pode gerar estes conflitos entre paths, sejam eles como no exemplo que dei ou mesmo entre **/sbin/node** e **/usr/bin/node**

Embora não faça parte do que você deseja fazer, você pode tentar fazer o teste de instalação deste package numa **máquina virtual** apenas para ver se ainda gera esse mesmo conflito.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atencao @FábioArsénio ! Olha acredito que nao estou a fazer sentir a minha pergunta, na verdade o problema ja tivera sido resolvido, gostaria no entanto saber a que se deve o conflito entre esses dois repertorios ? Porquê nodejs exige que o path para o binário seja usr/bin/node e não usr/bin/nodejs ? Estou a elaborar um relatorio e preciso explicar nao simplemente a resolucao do problema, mas também a causa !

Comment: Tive pesquisando e a ultima versão do nodejs exige que o path seja o tal /usr/bin/node , criando então este conflinto caso não esteja instalada esta package do legacy, a package do legacy vai forçar o update da path de uma versão mais antiga do nodejs para a mais recente, forçando tambem a alteração do path para o binário. Tudo isto através do symlink que a package contém

Comment: Se se tornar mais fácil eu posso acrescentar esta ultima informação à resposta! @AndréPKA

Comment: Agradeço @Fabio !  Se ainda tiver algumas informacoes podes acrescentar... MERCI !